# Merging controller lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

In my pages_controller.rb, I have the following defined for a user's profile page:

```
def profile
 if (User.find_by_username(params[:id]))
  @username = params[:id]
  @users = User.all.where("id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id)
  @posts = Post.all.where("user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id)
 else
  # redirect to 404 (root for now)
  redirect_to root_path, :notice=> "User not found"
 end
  @newPost = Post.new
end
```

As displayed above, I use this line to show posts on a profile page that only belong to that user:

```
@posts = Post.all.where("user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id)
```

However, I also want to add this line, which will only show posts that are less than a day old:

```
@posts = Post.where('created_at >= :seven_days_ago', seven_days_ago: Time.now - 7.days)
```

How do I merge these two together? I thought I can just do this:

```
@posts = Post.all.where("user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id, 'created_at >= :seven_days_ago', seven_days_ago: Time.now - 7.days)
```

But that isn't allowed. What's the proper fix?

Thanks!

Comment: first of all: you do not need to use `all` only when you do this `Post.all`

Comment: why is your `params[:id]` not the user_id but the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@posts = Post.all.where("user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id)
@posts = Post.where('created_at >= :seven_days_ago', seven_days_ago: Time.now - 7.days)
```

You could fix it by chaining two `where`.

```
@posts = Post.all.where("user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id)
                 .where('created_at >= :seven_days_ago', seven_days_ago: Time.now - 7.days)
```

More, you can use subquery instead of two separate query

```
@posts = Post.all.where(:user_id => User.where(:username => params[:id]))
                 .where('created_at >= :seven_days_ago', seven_days_ago: Time.now - 7.days)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much, I didn't know about the two ".where" trick!

Answer (score 0):

You got it almost right, should've use key arguments, though.
Here is the working solution

```
Post.where(user_id: User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id).where('created_at > ?', 7.days.ago)
```

Comment: @Fallenhero nah, I don't think so. It's rather illogical to display posts of any user on profile page

Comment: @NikitaMisharin everything in that worked except the ", created_at: 7.days.ago". It displayed no posts on the profile page.